# changing routes quickly triggers ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError (matsnackbar)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I have a navbar with two routes. Each route takes me to a component that `onInit` makes an http req to get information to display in a table. If the http is `200` but has no info I call a `service` that has `matsnackbar`s, and make a `matsnackbar.open(blabla)` to display an alert that "hey, there's no info here"

The problem is that when I toggle between those 2 routes quickly I get this error

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: '@state: undefined'. Current value: '@state: void'. It seems like the view has been created after its parent and its children have been dirty checked. Has it been created in a change detection hook ?
```

I tried to put the snackbar call in some other lifecycle hooks but I got the same error or an infinite loop.

Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what other lifecycle hooks have you tried using? And please post your template and ts code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually because the state has changed from the time it was checked before `ngOnInit` and during `ngOnInit`. The simplest way I've found to get rid of this warning is to throw the statement in a small timeout to let `ngOnInit` finish before opening a dialog or putting up a snackbar message. It will be unnoticeable to the user, and it will let Angular do its job properly.

```
ngOnInit() {
  // do stuff
  setTimeout(() => matsnackbar.open(blabla), 50);
  // do other stuff
}
```